# (Dis)prove a statement similar to Bessaga fixed point theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functions, functional-equations, functional-inequalities

> Prove or disprove that if $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<|x-y|$ for all different real numbers $x$, $y$, then $f(x)=x$ has a unique solution.

Firstly, there can't be $f(a)=a$ and $f(b)=b$ for different real numbers $a$, $b$, since
$$|a-b|>|f(a)-f(b)|=|a-b|$$
is absurd.

So we assume that $f(x)\ne x$ for all real numbers $x$ and see whether we arrive at another contradiction (proving the statement) or manage to find a counterexample (disproving the statement).

Let $A=\{x\mid f(x)>x\}$, $B=\{x\mid f(x)<x\}$, then $A$, $B$ form a partition of $\Bbb R$. Assuming there exists $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ such that $a>b$, then $f(a)>a>b>f(b)$, and so
$$|f(a)-f(b)|=f(a)-f(b)>a-b=|a-b|,$$
contradiction! So for all $a\in A$ and $b\in B$, we have $a<b$.

I am stuck here. After some thinking, perhaps whether $f(x)$ is greater or less than $x$ is not so important...?

Comment: One of the sets $A, B$ is necessarily empty by continuity of $f(x)-x$.

Comment: Well, the fixed point theorem that I know involving a contraction map is the Banach Fixed Point Theorem. To it works we need the hypothesis $\exists c < 1$ such that $\vert f(a) - f(b)\vert < c\vert a - b\vert$. Without that constant, the contraction map could not to have a "center of contraction", which is the fixed point (this is the basic idea of the proof of the Banach Fixed Point Theorem).

Comment: @DARK $x=0$ is the unique solution of $\sin x =x$.

Comment: The hypothesis implies that $f$ is continuous. [In fact, uniformly continuous, in fact Lipschitz!].

Comment: @geetha290krm I understand your point. So does this prove or disprove my statement?

Comment: @geetha290krm it has a fixed point at $x = 0$. But if you add an constant, say $1$, than the function $f(x) = \frac{\vert x\vert}{1 + \vert x \vert}x + 1$ is has no fixed point

Comment: @PauloEstêvão You can post this as a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counter-example: The function $f(x) = \frac{\vert x\vert}{1 + \vert x\vert}x + 1$ has no fixed point, however satisfies $\vert f(x) - f(y)\vert < \vert x - y\vert$.

Comment: Thanks. Inspired by your answer, I constructed a slightly complicator function$$f(x)=x-\arctan x+\frac\pi2.$$Maybe basically we try to let $y=x$ be an asymptote?

Comment: That's the idea.